# Chrome Extension: "TypeError: Error in invocation of history.search: No matching signature." when trying to get search history

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-history

When I run this code:

```
async function getSearchHistory(amount) {
    if (amount > 100) amount = 100; // API returns sub-arrays of 100 if >100 requested, breaking the program.
    console.log("Fetched " + amount + "latest history entries.");
    let queryOptions = {
            // Search for x amount latest history entries w/o filter.
            text: '',
            maxResults: amount,
            startTime: 0 // Cutoff date for search set as 0 in Unix epoch. Why bother putting a cap on it?
        };
    chrome.history.search(queryOptions);
    };
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Error in invocation of history.search(object query, function callback): No matching signature.

I have absolutely no clue what's causing it, since [I think I'm calling the API properly](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/history/#method-search). I'm passing in integers for the amount, a blank text filter (I want to fetch x amount latest history entries w/o any filter), and an integer for Unix time. Any and all help is appreciated! This is my first extension and this is hopefully the last bug to iron out before it's fully functional.

Comment: The error says it wants a callback.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe it was that simple... I must've read the wrong API documentation (probably mixed up deleteUrl and search) and thought it was optional =P.

Comment: P.S: How do I close this question now? I can't mark the comment as the answer... First time posting here, so I'm not really familiar.